# ¿Comó puedo obtener datos de un img con javascript alpresionar un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy desarrollando un modulo de productos que puedan tener varias imagenes que luego serán mostrados en un web ecommerce, ya tengo la carga de las imágenes, ahora deseo poder eliminar una imagen.

Al momento cargo las imagenes con ajax desde una función desde el controlador, y se muestra así.

[image: Carga de imagnes]

Y se muestran de la siguiente manera en el html

```
<div class="col container-img text-center" id="upload_5">
<span id="idimg">5</span>
 <div class="row">
  <img src="http://localhost/miuniformefacil/site2023/system/imgproductos/1688486928-4.jpg" height="150">
 </div>
 <div>
 <a id="adeleteimg" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger adeleteimg"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
 </div>
```

He intentado de varias manera llamarlo desde javascript pero no doy con la solución.

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
        var id = this.id;
        var split_id = id.split('_');
        var num = split_id[1];

        var img_src = $('#upload_'+num+' img').attr("src");
        var delete_file = confirm("Do you really want to Delete this file?");
        if (delete_file == true) {
            /*$.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {path: img_src,request_status: 2},
                success: function(response){
                    // Remove image
                    if(response == 1) {
                        $('#img_content'+num).remove();
                        $('#upload_'+num).remove();
                        $('#user_profile').val('');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

También así

```
$(".container-img").click(function(){
  alert("OK") 
 })
```

Dentro del document

```
$("#adeleteimg").click(function () {
alert("ok")
    })
```

No tengo mucha experiencia en javascript, espero me pueda ayudar a poder obtener los datos del span al hacer click en los botones.

Gracias

Comment: En tu código se ve que estás usando jQuery. ¿Necesitás que te respondan solo con jQuery o estás dispuesto/a a cambiarte a JS puro? (ya que no es bueno mezclar código)

Comment: Gracias, si me indicas en JS puro no hay problema

Comment: @padaleiana por qué `no es bueno mezclar código`?

Comment: @AndresGardiol Hacía referencia a mezclar código de JS puro con jQuery.

Comment: Mmm pero jQuery es una librería de javascript. Al usar ReactJs dirías que estás mezclando Js puro con React? Quizás no estoy entendiendo la diferencia

Comment: @AndresGardiol Claro que jQuery es una librería de JS. Una referencia de lo que comenté [es esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/166323). No es que "esté mal" per se, sino que no es recomendable.

Comment: Buen artículo! Sin embargo vi más [respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166324/86914) del tipo "no hay problema" que de las de tipo "no es recomendable". De todas formas es un punto a tener en cuenta. Gracias por la info!

Answer (score 0):

Primero tendrías que capturar a todos tus botones eliminar, que tienen la clase `adeleteimg`. Luego a cada botón le agregamos un listener para indicarle que si le damos clic en cierto botón, llamamos a la función `eliminarCard()`, quien se encarga de eliminar al card correspondiente donde se encuentra ese botón eliminar al quien dimos clic. Esto ocurre al pasarle `this` como argumento:

```
let botonesEliminar = document.getElementsByClassName('adeleteimg');

for (let i = 0; i < botonesEliminar.length; i++) {
  botonesEliminar[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    eliminarCard(this);
  });
}
```

Ahora, en la función `eliminarCard()` usamos al `parentNode` de `e` (quien es ese HTML del botón eliminar), esto sirve para **acceder al elemento padre** de ese botón eliminar (es decir, el elemento `div` quien encierra a ese botón). Luego usamos otro `parentNode` para acceder al siguiente elemento padre de ese `div`, quien sería todo el card, y ese card lo eliminamos con `remove()`.

```
function eliminarCard(e) {
  let card = e.parentNode.parentNode;
  card.remove();
}
```

Un ejemplo funcional sería el siguiente (removí los `id` ya que éstos deben ser únicos):

```js
function eliminarCard(e) {
  let card = e.parentNode.parentNode;
  card.remove();
}

let botonesEliminar = document.getElementsByClassName('adeleteimg');

for (let i = 0; i < botonesEliminar.length; i++) {
  botonesEliminar[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    eliminarCard(this);
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container d-flex gap-3 p-3">
  <div class="col container-img text-center">
    <span>1</span>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="pt-2">
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger adeleteimg"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col container-img text-center">
    <span>2</span>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="pt-2">
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger adeleteimg"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col container-img text-center">
    <span>3</span>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="pt-2">
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger adeleteimg"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col container-img text-center">
    <span>4</span>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="pt-2">
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger adeleteimg"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4d529f15e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Y para aplicarlo en tu AJAX, en el siguiente ejemplo indicamos que si se aceptó el mensaje de confirmación, se hace la petición AJAX, y dentro del `success` eliminamos el card correspondiente sólo si `response` es `1`:

```
function eliminarCard(e) {
  let card = e.parentNode.parentNode;
  let imgSrc = card.querySelector('.row img').getAttribute('src');

  if (confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminar este archivo?")) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { path: imgSrc, request_status: 2 },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == 1) {
          card.remove();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

let botonesEliminar = document.getElementsByClassName('adeleteimg');

for (let i = 0; i < botonesEliminar.length; i++) {
  botonesEliminar[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    eliminarCard(this);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias obtener los detalles de la imagen asignando el id_imagen en data-id del elemento al cual harás click y capturando el evento con JS Puro es más sencillo de lo que parece:
1.- Crea el contenedor de tus imagenes
2.- Renderiza en el tus imagenes
3.- Asigna los datos de tus imagenes
4.- Captura el evento
5.- Elimina tu imagen

```js
    // Simulacion de las imagenes //

    const images = [
      {
        "img_id": 1,
        "url": "https://trueloveandpoems.com/cdn/shop/articles/Insumos.png?v=1524116554"
      },
      {
        "img_id": 2,
        "url": "https://trueloveandpoems.com/cdn/shop/articles/Insumos.png?v=1524116554"
      },
      {
        "img_id": 3,
        "url": "https://trueloveandpoems.com/cdn/shop/articles/Insumos.png?v=1524116554"
      }
    ];

    
    // Contenedor donde se renderizarán las imagenes //
    let imgRender = document.querySelector("#upload_5");

   // Ahora debemos recorrer el array de las imagenes //
   function paintImages({ images }) {
    // Vaciamos el contenedor para evitar que se repitan datos //
    imgRender.innerHTML = '';
    
    // Recorremos el array y pintamos las imagenes //
    images.forEach(
      image => {
        imgRender.innerHTML += `
         <div>
           <span id="idimg">IMAGEN ID: ${image.img_id}</span>
           <div>
            <img src="${image.url}" height="150" />
           </div>
           <div>
             <button class="deleteImg" data-id="${image.img_id}">❌</button>
             <button class="checkImg" data-id="${image.img_id}"></button>
           </div>
         </div>
        `
      }
     )
   }
   
   paintImages({images})
   
   // Captura el evento click solo en el contenedor de las imagenes //
   imgRender.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    // Se esta haciendo click en delete ?
    if (event.target.classList.contains('deleteImg')) {
      const img_id = event.target.dataset.id
      if (!confirm("Desea eliminar la imagen: " + img_id)) return;
      // Buscamos la imagen con findIndex que retorna la posicion de la imagen seleccionada para que se pueda eliminar //
      const imgIndex = images.findIndex(
        img => img.img_id == img_id
      )
      
      if (imgIndex >= 0) {
        // Eliminamos la imagen //
        delete images[imgIndex]
        
        // Pintamos nuevamente las imagenes restantes //
        paintImages({ images })
      }
    }
   })
```

```css
#upload_5 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(15rem, 1fr));
  gap: 16px;
}

#upload_5 > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="" id="upload_5">
    
</div>
```

Espero te ayude suerte!

Comment: En vez de `alert`, podría ser mejor un `confirm`, y se proceda a eliminar si se aceptó el `confirm`.

Comment: Cierto, aunque existen otras alternativas 